# how to properly pass body in POST request flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, rest, dart

I'm using `HTTPClient` to make a `POST` request in flutter to post the `Form` Data, I have many fields in the form which I want to post but for now I had given only `firstname`, `lastname` and `email` in the parameters as well as the `body` on the request. But now I want to pass the entire `JSON` as body so that I can get the values of all the `FormFields`.

How can I properly achieve this?

My form contains `TextFormFields`, `DateTimeFormField` and also `DropdownButtonFormField`.

**API_Manager class:**

```
Future<AddContactModel> addContact(
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String email,
  ) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    String addContactUrl =
        "https://example.com/ma/api/contacts/new";
    String basicAuth = 'Basic examplebasicauthkey';
    var response = await client.post(addContactUrl, headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }, body: {
      "firstname": firstName,
      "lastname": lastName,
      "email": email
    });
    // print(response.statusCode);
    // developer.log(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final String responseString = response.body;
      return addContactModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

*As you can see from the code, the `body` contains only three fields. But I want to add all my fields so instead of giving all fields explicitly to the body, I though I could pass the `json` directly. I'm new to flutter so I don't know if it would work or not? I'll share my sample JSON data too.*

**JSON Sample Data:**

```
{
    "contact": {
        "isPublished": true,
        "id": 193208,
        "fields": {
            "core": {
                "firstname": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "label": "First Name",
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": "Richa"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "id": "3",
                    "label": "Last Name",
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": "Kumari"
                },
                "email": {
                    "id": "6",
                    "label": "Email",
                    "value": "richa@abc.com"
                },
            },
            "all": {
                "id": 193208,
                "firstname": "Richa",
                "lastname": "Kumari",
                "email": "richa@abc.com",
            }
        },
     "...": {
                             "..." : "..."
                            }
```

**UI Code:**

```
Future saveContact() async {
    final String firstName = _firstName.text;
    final String lastName = _lastName.text;
    final String email = _email.text;

    final AddContactModel contact =
        await API_Manager().addContact(firstName, lastName, email);

    setState(() {
      _contact = contact;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Add Contact'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    await saveContact();
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'SAVE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                shape:
                    CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  _contact == null
                      ? Container()
                      :
                      //Text("The user ${_contact.contact.fields.all.firstname} is created successfully at time ${_contact.contact.lastActive.toIso8601String()}"),
                      TextFormField(
                          onSaved: null,
                          controller: _ipCountryCode,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'IP Country Code',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                        ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Time First Seen',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              timeFirstSeen = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _eventRevenue,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Event Revenue',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _sendsSinceLastEngagement,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Sends since last engagement',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _marketingEmailsOpened,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Marketing Emails Opened',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Last marketing email click date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              lastMarketingEmailClickDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email Address Quarantined',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: emailAddressQuarantined,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              emailAddressQuarantined = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: emailAddressQuarantinedItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _socialAwarenessClicks,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Social Awareness Clicks',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Lead Status',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: leadStatus,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              leadStatus = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: leadStatusItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Create date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              createDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Became an evangelist date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              becameAnEvangelistDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _firstName,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _lastName,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Last Name',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    //validator: validateEmail,
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _email,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _reasonForEmailUnsubscribe,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Reason for email unsubscribe',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Tags',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: tags,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              tags = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: tagsItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Select a company',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: selectCompany,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectCompany = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: selectCompanyItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Contact Owner',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: contactOwner,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              contactOwner = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: contactOwnerItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Stage',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: stage,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              stage = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: stageItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

**As you can in the method `saveContact()`, the values of `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` and being posted successfully because it is in the body of the API call, but how will that code change when the body will have the entire JSON data? how should I access all the other field values?**

Comment: Your json is a `Map<String, dynamic>` object. Call it for example `Map<String, dynamic> jsonTobePosted`. in your request body, use => `body: jsonTobePosted`.

Comment: I did not understand actually, my JSON data is very huge and I've created a model object for it which I'm returning in the method, I want to know if I should explicitly give the complete JSON body to `jsonTobePosted` and then add that to body? if I do that the code would look very bad.

Comment: Your model class should have a ToJson function if not you can create it and use it to send data. This is the best way.

Comment: I do have that function in my model class but i don't know where to put it in the code, do i have to return it or throw it in the body? I'm not sure, could you help me with that?